# How can I fill a shape in Radar Chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2019

I'm struggling to find a way to just fill one shape in a radar chart.
An example of what I would like to have is in the image.

- I tried to start from a simple radar chart and then filling the shape --> I can't find the option;
- I tried to start from a filled radar chart, but I don't know how to obtain the result in the image;

Thank you.

[image: Filled Radar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a series data for the filled shape in Radar Chart?

If not, please add an auxiliary column to draw the line for this filled shape.

Then create a Radar Chart includes the series of auxiliary column.

And then select this chart > Recommended Chart > All Charts tab > Combo > Choose Filled Radar for the series of auxiliary column. Choose Radar for another series > OK.

[image]

[image]

If you need to show markers you may add it.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I am really grateful. Thank you.